# Sass with themes_for_rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes

I am using [themes_for_rails](https://github.com/lucasefe/themes_for_rails) gem and trying to get it works with Sass.

I tryed the default configuration (themes are stored in root/themes) and the solution with themes stored in root/app/assets/themes.

All my "*.scss" files are not compiled.

I tryed to debug this and founded that themes_for_rails was not able to load Sass::Plugin when it check "sass_is_available?" in "[lib/themes_for_rails/config.rb](https://github.com/lucasefe/themes_for_rails/blob/master/lib/themes_for_rails/config.rb)"-

Does anyone have a solution for this?

**EDIT:**

Server run on an apache with passenger.

**EDIT:**

I did a [fork](https://github.com/codesource/themes_for_rails) for this gem to resolve this problem.

- With the original gem from lucasefe scss/sass file should be stored in a "sass" folder in each folder/subfolder and generated css are stored in the folder that contain the "sass" folder.
- With the fork, generated css can be stored in a cache folder and controller get them when needed, so generated css will not pollute your stylesheets folder.